# Sort Active Admin index by named scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have a model `Slider` with a named scope:

```
scope :positioned, order("CASE WHEN position = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC").order("position ASC").order("created_at DESC")
```

This adds a somewhat complex ordering. I'd like my ActiveAdmin to re-use that scope. 
So far, I can only order by a column, like so:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Slider do
  config.sort_order = "position_asc"
end
```

How can I import, re-use or force the ordering from the named scope in the active-admin index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your version of ActiveAdmin try putting this in your `Slider` model:

```
default_scope :order("CASE WHEN position = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC").order("position ASC").order("created_at DESC")
```

Make sure you read this https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/352

good luck!